# Wait() function makes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, fork, wait

When I run this code, i have "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
Apparently it comes from the wait() section but I can't figure it out.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{   
pid_t pid, pid2;
int etat;
char** entree_util;
entree_util[0]="none";
char * accueil = "Veuillez entrer votre commande\n";
while (entree_util[0]!="^D")
{
    write(1,accueil, strlen(accueil)*sizeof(char) );
    entree_util=lis_ligne();
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==-1)
    {
        perror("Erreur à l'appel de fork\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid==0)
    {
    execv(entree_util[0],entree_util+1);
    }
    else
    {
         pid2 = wait(&etat);
    }
}
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say where the crash is?

Comment: What does your _compiler_ tell you (the warnings I mean)

Comment: that's because you're not enabling the warnings

Answer (score 1):

The first instance of undefined behavior in your code is

```
char** entree_util;
entree_util[0]="none";
```

`entree_util` is an uninitialized pointer.

You should probably change your loop structure:

```
char** entree_util;

while (1)
{
    write(1, accueil, strlen(accueil));  // note: sizeof (char) is 1 by definition
    entree_util = lis_ligne();
    if (we_are_finished(entree_util)) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that `entree_util[0] != "^D"` doesn't make sense as a condition; you're not comparing strings here, you're comparing pointers. The correct condition depends on what `lis_ligne` returns, which you haven't shown.

Alternatively you can move the logic for prompting the user and reading a line into a separate helper function:

```
char **lis_ligne_avec_invite_de_commande(const char *accueil) {
    write(1, accueil, strlen(accueil));
    return lis_ligne();
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
char** entree_util;
while (!we_are_finished(entree_util = lis_ligne_avec_invite_de_commande("Veuillez entrer votre commande\n"))
{
    ...
}
```